# Alsa: snd_pci_readi() recording

Tags: real-time, alsa, libalsa

I've got a dedicated thread that caputures audio from Alsa through `snd_pcm_readi()`. Recording happens fine for some 30 mins (each file of one minute duration), After that file size gradually decreases  and results in "**read from audio interface failed  err = -32**"

```
if ((err = snd_pcm_readi(capture_handle, buffer, buffer_frames)) != buffer_frames)

{

        fprintf (stderr, "read from audio interface failed (%s)\n",err, snd_strerror (err));
            audio_outbuf_size = (err * snd_pcm_format_width(AUDIO_FORMAT)/ 8 * 2);
}
```

Any helps are apperciated.
Thank you.

Comment: -32 is -EPIPE, which would indicate an overrun. What should happen in that case?

Comment: i am recording videos continuously(of each one  minute duration), after this error "read from audio interface failed err = -32", video file size gradually decreases, and then files results in 1kb or 2kb files which is non playable. please suggest me how to overcome "overrun error".

Comment: An overrun means that your program did not read samples fast enough, so some were lost. What should happen in this case?

Comment: how can i achieve this in the right way..?

Comment: What should happen when some samples are lost? Abort? Restart? Replace with zeros?

Comment: No, i should not miss any samples. i need all the data to be fine.

Comment: ALSA uses a ring buffer. If you do not read samples in time, they are lost.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the chances of an overrun, increase the buffer size. For best results, make it as large as possible.

As long as the period size stays the same, latency will not change.